# Apply security checks on <iframe>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I am working on a education based project wherein I am using `<iframe>` to show some `pdf` files for reading. I want to disable right `click, cut, copy` and `download` from the `<iframe>` content which seems to be impossible. I have seen a few web portals in which all this features are embedded. I want to apply on mine too, can somebody tell how can this be implemented. Upon that, when I run the file on Firefox, it does not displays the iframe with PDF but it downloads automatically but it does displays on Chrome . I had been searching so many times but not yet able to stop above said issues. Any advice or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

```
<body>
    <iframe id ="p" src="ppt1.pdf#toolbar=0" width="60%" height="70%" ></iframe>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

var DEFAULT_URL = 'ppt1.pdf';

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#p').bind('cut copy paste', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("#p").on("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't adding an event listener for "contextmenu" to the iframe handle this? Search the web for "javascript disable right click" (without the quotes).

This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Thank you for this. But i would like to mention that i used the javascript script for click, copy and select all but it does not applies on iframe tag .

Comment: Did you add an event listener specifically to the iframe? An iframe acts like a separate entity in many ways.

Comment: I have added and edited my question. Please take a look. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You still don't have event listeners **on the iframe**. Add an `id` to the frame and assign it the same event listeners you have assigned to `"body"`.

Comment: Tried that too. No success on this too. Can something else be done??